# Get dynamic src using iframe

Tags: html, iframe, src

The template code is like this:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
   ...
    <iframe width="100%" height="300px" src="http://www.bing.com" name="iframe_a">    </iframe>
 </html>
```

But I would like to have the embedded frame search some string which is obtained outside the iframe, i.e. http://www.bing.com/search?q=(some string)

What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, give the `iframe` an `id`:

```
<iframe id="myIframe" width="100%" height="300px" src="http://www.bing.com" name="iframe_a">    </iframe>
```

---

Update based on your comments:

**PHP**

```
<?php 
$search = "test";
?>
```

---

**JavaScript:**

```
<script>
var currentSrc = document.getElementById('myIframe').src;
document.getElementById('myIframe').src = currentSrc + "search?q=<?php echo $search; ?>";
</script>
```

---

[CODEPEN DEMO](http://codepen.io/tuga/pen/gpYvMB)

Comment: Are the last three lines in html or what? @Pedro Lobito

Comment: I see your point. But my value is obtained inside php, how can I pass the value into the javascript. @Pedro Lobito